# Drawing a line between two button components

Tags: c#, graphics, controls

so I'm trying to find a way to draw a straight line between two buttons that I have clicked on (There are multiple source->destination lines to draw). I am currently using this code.

```
    private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        using (Graphics g = e.Graphics)
        {
            foreach (Connection c in connections)
            {
                Point pt1 = c.source.Location;
                Point pt2 = c.destination.Location;

                using (Pen p = new Pen(Brushes.Black))
                {
                    g.DrawLine(p, pt1, pt2);
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

Now this works, but obviously it is drawing on my form canvas and it hidden behind all my buttons that are on my form. Here is what the layout looks like:

[image]

Is there anyway I can fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: Wow, how long does that screen take to draw? Are they all buttons? Maybe you should take a look at a different approach where you draw your contents on the canvas and handle interactions that way?

Comment: It takes 2 seconds to draw, I want to handle it this way first then I will change it.

Comment: Okay, the main problem (that you have already encountered) is that anything on the canvas will appear behind all of your controls so it is how much time you invest working around this before you consider another approach.

Answer (score 0):

Each button knows its relative position on parent and each can handle its `Paint` event. If you store your lines in some colletion in form of their line equation that goes through two points **(x2-x1)(y-y1)=(y2-y1)(x-x1)**, you will be able to iterate through them in button `Paint` handler and calculate whether the line crosses the button's edges or not. Each button should have own equation of its edges with respect to its parent coordinates.